# Twitter Premium API

Tags: twitter

I hope you guys are best with your health and development works. I encountered a problem i.e. Twitter is not giving me maximum amounts of tweets, and I am not satisfied with premium. For sure, there will be my development fault. I’d diagnosed with a problem below, can you guys please tell me what will be the best possible solution for this? 
**Moreover can you please tell me the reason why I am not getting maximum amount of tweets WHEN NO FILTERS ARE APPLIED TO THE RULE?**

```
SEARCH_TWEETS_URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/development.json'

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)} 
payload = {"query": (hash_one) -is:retweet} 

response = requests.get(SEARCH_TWEETS_URL,params=payload,headers=headers).json()
```

whereas, **hash_one is the user input of #tags or @TwitterHandles or Keywords.**
I want to negate the retweets , in which pycharm IDE is giving me syntax error.

I’d also tried with hard-coded handles, #tags:

```
payload = {"query": "(@thePSLt20) -is:retweet"}
```

But its searches for “hash_one” and results me in empty string of tweets.

Its not working either way. :/

Please help :)